# algorithm for making letters out of text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, image

does anyone know of an algorithm that uses small images or letters spell out bigger letters?  For example, if I want to spell out the letter T:

[image: T]

or E:

[image: E]

what if instead of using letters, I wanted to use an image for each block?

In particular, I'd like to do this on the iPhone.

Comment: also, what is this algorithm or process called?

Comment: Well you could look into font rasterization (from vector font formats), and then use letters instead of pixels although that might be overkill... Otherwise I can't see anything else other than specifying the character string with spaces and new lines for each individual letter.

Comment: FIGlet calls it 'alphabet' font - http://www.figlet.org/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

Relevant Figlet fonts:

- ftp://ftp.plig.org/pub/figlet/fonts/contributed/alphabet.flf
- ftp://ftp.plig.org/pub/figlet/fonts/contributed/letters.flf
- ftp://ftp.plig.org/pub/figlet/fonts/contributed/doh.flf

For images, replace each character with an image.

Answer (score 0):

We sed to do this on the old line printers in the '70s, also paper leaders.

I have used two options to do this:

1. Create an array, probably a chat array, for each character.
2. For early LD displays I reated the entire alphabet of interest in Graphic Converter, saved it the simplest smiliest graphic format possible, .bmp might be a good choice. THen wrote a program that could read the raw graphic file and create char arrays. This worked well when I needed several fonts.